# NoSuchMethodError in org.json.JSONObject after kubernetes upgrade from 1.21 to 1.23

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, org.json

I don't know if the kubernetes upgrade has anything to do with the problem, but it's the only change I know of between the time the application was working as expected and when it started throwing this exception.

I have some code in a Spring Boot app that adds a List<Object> to a JSONObject.  The line looks like this:

`jsonObject.put("some_name", someList);`

This code hasn't been touched in a year, but suddenly started throwing this exception after a k8s upgrade from 1.21 to 1.23:

`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.json.JSONObject org.json.JSONObject.put(java.lang.String, java.util.Collection)'   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1082)`

[...]

`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.json.JSONObject org.json.JSONObject.put(java.lang.String, java.util.Collection)'  at com.example.service.MyClass.convertToJson(MyClass.java:109)`

The k8s upgrade also included a change from Java 17.0.5+8 to Java 17.0.6+10, but everything runs as expected locally using both of those JDK versions.

I ran a `mvn dependency tree -Dverbose` and couldn't find anything weird there either. These were the only entries that had to do with json.

`org.json:json:jar:20220320`

`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.6.4`

I'm out of ideas for what might be causing this issue, so any suggestions on what to look at next are welcome.

Comment: Kubernetes doesn't care if you are running java in any version. Upgrading k8s can't do this. You changing your container image can.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you, which is why I'm so confused.  The manifest says the CONTAINER_IMAGE_TAG is exactly the same in the nonprod (broken) and prod (still working as expected) environments.  I didn't touch our deployment configuration between the time the app was working and when it broke.  I keep looking for anything else that might cause this.

Comment: You stated "This code hasn't been touched in a year" but also "included a change from Java 17.0.5+8 to Java 17.0.6+10". So the application has been rebuilt, and the least the application image. What happens when you deploy your original image, the completely unmodified one?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the application was last rebuilt in December.  The image is tagged "1.4.35-6c78abc-20221205-32".  Some aspects of the deployed instance seem to have changed, such as the Java runtime environment, but the image itself looks like the same version.  I don't know enough detail about how kubernetes works under the covers to know if that makes sense.

Comment: Kubernetes unit of execution is a Pod, in the pod are 1+ containers (like a docker container). Containers are build with everything they need to run as a "container image" that is added to a registry where kubernetes can get it during the deployment. There is a line `image: registry/imageName:version` in the container definition. Your problematic "container image" must be different to the one you have in your production system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that the version of org.json:json included in your project is out of date, and doesn't include the put(String, Collection) method you're trying to use. Try updating this dependency to a more recent version and seeing if that resolves the issue. It's also possible there are some other dependencies in your project which conflict with org.json:json or override it with an older version - check for any similarly named libraries (e.g., json-simple instead of org.json). You may also want to check the version of Spring Boot you're using, as this might be incompatible with the org.json library you're trying to use.

Comment: I already checked most of those things, but I appreciate the suggestion.  Everything works as expected in most environments with the exact same application build, so I don't think it's a version conflict.

Comment: I never did figure out why the application ever worked in the first place, but I fixed the NoSuchMethodError.  The spring-boot-starter-test dependency was incorrectly included with "compile" scope instead of "test".  This resulted in a conflict between the JSONObject class from org.json and another class with the same name in the org.skyscreamer.jsonassert test library.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my Springboot project,
though the scope of spring-boot-starter-test dependency set to test android-json was getting picked up at runtime instead of org.json. Excluding the android-json worked for me.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
 <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>  
</dependency>
```